# Parameter Not Valid error in JpegBitmapDecoder

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

The error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
```

Occurs in the line

`decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, bitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);`

Stack trace is

```
at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

> 

The program performs image manipulation on groups of JPEG files.

The function containing the line is called repeatedly (for different images) from GetWindowsTags and SetWindowsTags and failure occurs after a variable number of calls, but sometimes more quickly with larger images, implying a memory problem. However, monitoring with Task Manager shows no systematic increase in memory use with repeated calls. The non-repeatable nature of the error (it cannot be handled by a try-catch structure) makes it hard to see what is causing it.

The full function in the class  **JpegMetadataAdapter** is

```
private BitmapFrame getBitmapFrame(string path)
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = null;
        using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }
        BitmapFrame bf = decoder.Frames[0];
        decoder= null;           
        return bf;
    }
```

The function getBitmapFrame is called from

```
public JpegMetadataAdapter(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
        frame = getBitmapFrame(path);

        Metadata = (BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata.Clone();
        //Metadata = (BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata;
    }
```

Metadata is retrieved by the function

```
public static void GetWindowsTags(string sFile, ref string Title, ref string Subject, ref string Comment, bool bShowError = false)
    {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            JpegMetadataAdapter jpeg = new JpegMetadataAdapter(sFile);
            Comment = (jpeg.Metadata.Comment + "").Trim();
            Title = (jpeg.Metadata.Title + "").Trim();
            Subject = (jpeg.Metadata.Subject + "").Trim();                              
            return;

    }
```

and set by the function

```
public static void SetWindowsTags(string sFile, string sFileOut, string Title = "", string Subject = "", string Comment = "", bool bShowError = false)
    {
            var jpeg = new JpegMetadataAdapter(sFile);               
            jpeg.Metadata.Comment = Comment;
            jpeg.Metadata.Title = Title;
            jpeg.Metadata.Subject = Subject;
            jpeg.SaveAs(sFileOut);               
            return;
        }
```

GetWindowsTags is called 3 times in the processing loop for each input file and SetWindowsTags once

The following code sometimes results in an 'insufficient memory' error, but not reproducibly. The string array  `LocalFilesToShow` 
contains 118 paths to JPEG files. This behaviour is very odd and perhaps points to something amiss in System.Drawing.dll on my Win 10 machine.

```
//test of error in GetWindowsTags
                List<string> SearchResults = new List<string>();
                 for (int i = 0;  i < LocalFilesToShow.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                {
                    string sTitle = "";
                    string sSubject = "";
                    string sComment = "";
                    GetWindowsTags(LocalFilesToShow[i], ref sTitle, ref sSubject, ref sComment);
                    if ((sTitle+ sSubject).IndexOf("NT") != 0)SearchResults.Add(LocalFilesToShow[i]);                      
                }`
```

Comment: Your SaveAs is missing, and since you are setting properties on a MetaDataClone that might be if interest.

Comment: Could you post a better stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace added.

Comment: There is a SaveAs in the SetWindowsTag function

Comment: Added detail of another error with repeated calls to GetWindowsTags

Comment: I have lost track here. Be aware that GDI+ used to throw OutOfMemory for invalid (damaged) files. Otherwise, try for an [mcve], see if you can reproduce this in  a small console app without all the windows stuff.

Comment: I've been trying to create a small example but the non-reproducibility makes it very hard. I'm currently sidestepping the problem by using EXIF rather than Windows metadata, set using ImageMagick. Thanks for your interest in the problem.

Comment: After recoding to avoid using JpegMetadata I still occasionally get a Parameter Not Valid unhandled error when creating a bitmap from a file. The error occurs more frequently when Resource Monitor shows a large proportion of committed memory from applications such as browsers with a lot of tabs open. However, the application does not seem to commit a large amount of memory and when it crashes the memory allocation is not unusual. On Win 7 there is substantial free memory shown. The app commits more memory with bigger images and crashes are more frequent then. Still puzzled!